# Is translation a more relevant skill when learning a foreign language more closely related to your native language?

Tags: translation

Anecdotally, I've encountered people online who consider language learning closely related to translation.  This took me by surprise, since I consider learning foreign languages to be weakly associated with translation (maybe translation could function as a form of scaffolding to get early learners started), and if anything, I feel the student should avoid translation, and the advanced student in particular should use monolingual dictionaries.

The thing is, I'm learning Chinese (Mandarin) as a native English speaker, which are fairly distinct languages.  But maybe if I were learning, say, German, translation skills might be more relevant.

**Question**:  Is translation a more relevant skill when learning a foreign language more closely related to your native language?

Comment: Use whatever tools help you to understand/learn/remember the words. For example, to learn the French word "pierre", I *could* just write down the translation 'stone'. But in this case, if I look at the etymology (in a monolingual dictionary), I see that it comes from 'petra', which I can recognize as related to the word family "petrify", so in this case that's more memorable for me than a simple translation. Of course it takes longer to look up etymologies and monolingual explanations, so that's sometimes a disadvantage in some contexts (e.g. you've got a lot of words to look up).

Comment: Translation unless used by a professional trying to learn another related language is useless to students.  The translation methods of language learning are widely discredited.